# Fix for PHP parsing plain text?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, csv, plaintext

I have a php script which I am using to parse some plain text to a CSV format.

```
<?php
  $text = "1. Bonus: Name some things about US history. For 10 points each:
[10] Name the first president of the United States of America.
ANSWER: George Washington
[10] How many original colonies were there?
ANSWER: 13
[10] How many states exist today?
ANSWER: 50";


function text_to_csv( $text = null ) {
  $lines  = explode( "\n", $text );
  $data   = array();
  $temp   = array();
  foreach( $lines as $line ) {
    $line = trim( $line );
    if ( empty( $line ) ) {
      continue;
    }    
    if ( preg_match( '/^\[10\](.+?)$/', $line, $quest ) ) {
        $temp[] =  trim( $quest[0] );
        continue;
    }
    if ( preg_match( '/^([0-9]+)\.(.+?)$/', $line, $quest ) ) {
      $temp[] = trim( $quest[1] );
      $temp[] = trim( $quest[2] );
      continue;
    }
    if ( preg_match( '/^ANSWER\:(.+?)$/', $line, $quest ) ) {
      $temp[] = trim( $quest[1] );
      $data[] = "|".implode( '|,|', $temp )."|";
      $temp = array();
    }

    }

  return implode( "\r\n", $data );
}

echo text_to_csv( $text );
?>
```

This returns:

```
|1|,|Bonus: Name some things about US history. For 10 points each:|,|[10] Name the first president of the United States of America.|,|George Washington|
|[10] How many original colonies were there?|,|13|
|[10] How many states exist today?|,|50|
```

The second and third [10] are on separate lines and do not coincide with the first. What I would like the output to be is:

```
|1|,|Bonus: Name some things about US history. For 10 points each:|,|[10] Name the first president of the United States of America.|,|George Washington|,|[10] How many original colonies were there?|,|13|,|[10] How many states exist today?|,|50|
```

The entire string is all on one line and separated by commas. I think what is happening is the script is treating the second and third [10] as new entries rather than connected to the previous array. Can anybody help me fix this. It would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ignore the colors. I didn't mean for them to show.

Comment: @Robert Could you help explain? I'm fairly novice with PHP scripting.

Comment: What output format do youwant?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im A csv format. I have the example above.

Answer (score 1):

some texts have a simple carriage return character `\r`, others a line feed character `\n`, others has both carriage return and line feed character `\r\n`. That depends on the editor used to create the text.

You need to cover these possible situations. Do this:

`return implode("\r",implode("\n",implode("\r\n",$data)));`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using implode or even temp arrays ect, just use string concatenation. Most likely faster too, but upto you.

```
<?php
$text = "1. Bonus: Name some things about US history. For 10 points each:
[10] Name the first president of the United States of America.
ANSWER: George Washington
[10] How many original colonies were there?
ANSWER: 13
[10] How many states exist today?
ANSWER: 50";

function text_to_csv( $text = null ){
    $data   = null;
    $lines  = explode("\n",trim($text));

    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        $line = trim($line);
        if(empty($line))
        {
            continue;
        }
        if(preg_match('/^\[10\](.+?)$/', $line, $quest))
        {
            $data .= "|".trim( $quest[0] )."|,";
        }
        if(preg_match('/^([0-9]+)\.(.+?)$/', $line, $quest))
        {
            $data .= "|".trim( $quest[1] )."|,";
            $data .= "|".trim( $quest[2] )."|,";
        }
        if(preg_match('/^ANSWER\:(.+?)$/', $line, $quest))
        {
            $data .= "|".trim( $quest[1] )."|,";
        }
    }
    return rtrim($data, ',');
}

echo text_to_csv($text);

/*
|1|,|Bonus: Name some things about US history. For 10 points each:|,|[10] Name the first president of the United States of America.|,|George Washington|,|[10] How many original colonies were there?|,|13|,|[10] How many states exist today?|,|50|
*/
?>
```

Comment: Will this work if, say, I put two sets of bonuses in the $text variable?

Comment: It would build the output exactly the same as implode would do, but without doing unnecessary array handling. Dont know what you mean about bonuses, its just a string to me